# How to find View from string instead of R.id

Tags: android, resources

Let's assume I have this in layout of res in my app

```xml
<TextView android:id="@+id/titleText" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#ffffffb0" android:padding="5px" />
```

In my activity, I get the TextView using this command

```java
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleText);
```

But I am looking for another method like this

```java
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewByString("R.id."+"titleText");
```

Because I need to enumerate those ids. Can any of you give a hint or clue how I can go about it?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int id = res.getIdentifier("titleText", "id", getContext().getPackageName());
```

And then use the id.

Comment: and what about in kotlin?

Comment: @JrJimnz - You use exactly the same method calls and just change the syntax for declaring the variables. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702479/get-androids-id-resource-from-a-string) for instance.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can use this line to get the ID.

```
val id: Int = resources.getIdentifier("titleText", "id", packageName)
```

The returned value can be use as parameter of the function `findViewById<TextView>(id)`.

NOTE: If is called outside of an activity use the context.

```
val id: Int = context.resources.getIdentifier("titleText", "id", context.packageName)
```