# Get android's id resource from a string

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, kotlin

In my Kotlin app I have some `ImageViews` (in **`activity_main.xml`**): `imageView_0`, `imageView_1`, `imageView_2` and `imageView_3`.

How can I access the view in a loop from 0 to 3? This won't work:

```
val imageView: ImageView = findViewById<ImageView>("R.id.imageView_" + index) as ImageView
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for(i in 1..3){
  val id: int=getResources().getIdentifier("imageview_"+i, "id", 
  getPackageName())
  imageview[i]=findViewById(id) as ImageView
}
```

If you have in the **`xml`**, `imageview_1`, `imageview_2`, `imageview_3`

Answer (score 2):

Another option allowing to declare your array with not-nullable `ImageView`s:

```
val imageViews : Array<ImageView> = Array(4, {
    val id: Int = resources.getIdentifier("imageView_" + it, "id", packageName)
    findViewById<ImageView>(id)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
var imageViews: Array<ImageView?> = arrayOfNulls(4)

for (i in 0..3) {
    val id: Int = getResources().getIdentifier("imageView_" + i, "id", getPackageName())
    imageViews.set(i, findViewById<ImageView>(id) as ImageView)
}
```