# How can I retrieve an Android resource from its name (in Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

I want to play some raw audio files from a media player. But in my fragment, I only have access to the name of the file, i.e. "yeet".

Can I generate the resource file from the name alone, and then pass it to the media player?

```
var resFileName: String? = null
for (it in mItemList) {
    val resName = mItemList.find { it.first == uniqueId }?.second
    resFileName = "R.raw.$resName"
}

// Get raw resource from name and play sound
val raw = view!!.context.assets.open("$resFileName.mp3")
mp = MediaPlayer.create(view!!.context, raw) // This doesn't work; requires URI! or Int
```

**Edit:** Can we re-open this to address Kotlin syntax?

***My Answer:***

```
val raw = view!!.context.resources.getIdentifier("$resFileName",
        "raw", view.context.packageName)
println("Resource Name: $raw")

mp!!.reset()
mp = MediaPlayer.create(view.context, raw)
mp!!.start()
```

Comment: Can we re-open this to address Kotlin syntax?

Comment: Are you having issues calling `getResources().getIdentifier(`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I just figured this out.

Comment: Similar post here, but for layout ids. Same syntax as Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702479/kotlin-get-androids-id-resource-from-a-string